# Form in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with a form in my Web API. The form is very simple. The user enters a string, the controller receives the string and inserts it into a database with an id. The connection with the database works and I can read from it safely.

**EDIT**  This is the code in the controller.
**EDIT 2** This is the correct and working controler

```
public ActionResult PostMyData(string json) 
{
        try
        {
            var newEntry = new Questions() { Id = json.Id, Question= json.Question};
            context.Questions.Add(newEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
}
```

This is a part of the HTML page. **EDIT** 
This is the updated script that does not return errors.
**EDIT 2** This is the correct and working script

```
<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#submitButt', function () {
        var myquestion = $('#question').val();
        var json = {
            Id : 1,
            Question: myquestion
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/Simple",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("An Issue has occured");
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: That isn't a question or a useful description of the issue.  Please read [What do you mean "it doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: can you provide us the error ? and put your question in the post not in the coment , to be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your scenario, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="question" name="question" />
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Send"/>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '#submitBtn', function () {
    var myquestion=$('#question').val();
    var json = {
      myquestion: myquestion
     };

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "api/Simple/PostMyData",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify(json),
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
       },
       error: function (data) {
        alert("An Issue has occured");
       }
    });
}) 
</script>
```

And your `Controller` will look like:

```
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] string json) 
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

        //Get your variables here from AJAX call
        var myquestion= jsondata["myquestion"];
        try
        {
            var newEntry = new Question() { Id = 1, Question= myquestion};
            context.Question.Add(newEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the controller does not seem to be receiving the request.
I believe the problem is in URL.

Comment: @Luiss.PEP Maybe there might be some error on the JS side. Also could you change the action method name to something more meaningful here like `public ActionResult PostMyData(string json)` . Also see my edit to the buttons that you have defined. I have added an `id` field

Comment: I keep getting "An Issue has occured",I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Are you able to hit the Controller method while debugging ? It might have to do with your db context.

Comment: The controller is not hit, I don't understand if the problem is from the script or controller side. The context works for reading data entered through an external query.

Comment: Check you console on your browser. It will show if there are any errors in your script. Also you have not set id for your name input. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I just have to solve the problem on deserealization 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'.

Comment: Do you get any value in your `string json` ?

Comment: No it is null. if I try to insert a string instead of the one received, the code to save works.

Comment: Did you apply the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your ActionMethod ?

Comment: Yes, I entered [HttpPost ("PostMyData")].

Comment: Your `AJAX` url is incorrect. Try doing it in my way.

Comment: If I use your url it gives me the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". If I use api / Simple / PostMyData it gives me the error on the value, but executes any code that is not related to the value.

Comment: Do you get any value here: `myquestion = $('#question').val();`

Comment: Yes, I get my question and if I call alert (json) I get [object object]. 
Cannot send questions directly as a string?

Comment: @Luiss.PEP I am not quite sure what you are seeing in your `string json` value. If you getting the `question` value correct in your javascript, you should be able to get the value in your `Controller`

Comment: @Luiss.PEP You can try my updated answer as per your `API`

Comment: In the end, thanks to you, I solved the problem. You can see the final solution in my question.